# Linking Laravel project with MAMP database

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I am following a tutorial on creating a social network with Laravel v5.2. However the person in the tutorial uses Vagrant/Homestead but for the life of me I could not get that working so I resorted to MAMP to view my site locally. But now I have hit another roadblock.

I am trying to configure the ".env" file to connect to my MAMP database so that the migrations that have been written can be executed by I don't know how to go about this?

This is my ".env" file.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:7dP18Ga9X3wiFP6wQgUy6UsMu+RrgrU2QpkT4gyDUpI=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=uniteDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

"UniteDB" is the database I created in the MAMP PHPMy Admin but that did not work and I don't know where to go from here. If I try run "PHP artisan migrate" on the command line within my project file it returns

"[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am new to PHP/Laravel so I have no clue on how to get this to work.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message suggest some problem of syntax in some file, try to regerenate the .env file, and the key php artisan key:generate. Maybe that helps.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? type `php -v` in your terminal to find out.

Comment: Also - check your laravel.log file - there may be some more information there that will help you find the problem.

Comment: @MikeStivala PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a syntactical error. Most decent IDEs will highlight or underline the error in your project files. It is likely that the issue is in some of your migration files (based on the $table variable) but it could also be in any place that contains code being executed when migrating (e.g.: the Schema class).

It sounds like you have a missing semicolon in your migration file. show me your migration file if you cannot solve the problem

Comment: I'm just using a normal text editor for this project. If you know of any good free IDEs though let me know :) 

Can't show my full migration, but this is the only schema class I've used. 

public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
}

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem I was missing a curly bracket in the migration file. However I now have [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined function string()

Comment: Look like you are missing `>` this time in migration file, `ex:. $table-string('last_name');' should be `$table->string('last_name');`   donot forget to upvote me if it useful for you

Comment: I will recommend you using the jetbrains also knows as php storm editor or netbeans,

Comment: Thank you! It has completed the migration. Every time I think it's the computer playing up but it's little mistakes like that. Thanks man.